# Cube processing is slow when select each ssas objects in SSIS Analysis Services Processing Task

Tags: oracle, ssis, ssas, cube, msbi

[image][image]I am processing the cube using SSIS packages which is scheduled in SQL Server agent job. In SSIS package I am selecting just ssas DB name under Analysis Services Processing Task. it takes around 5 hours.
In the same SSIS package and Analysis services Processing Task, when I select each ssas objects (all dimensions and partitions) individually instead of just ssas DB name, the cube processing time is getting increased. then it takes approx 9-10 hours.
Anyone has idea/suggestion, please help?

I have tried to resolve this by configuring multiple options of parallelism in 'Change Setting' option of analysis Services processing task.
Also made sure that the edition and version of ssas should be same in development + deployment environment(enterpriseCore64 / 12.0)

Comment: I think you should provide some information about the database/objects such as size, number of partitions, machine specification.

Comment: When you process the whole database is it a ProcessFull? When you choose individual objects do you do ProcessFull on each or might you be doing ProcessUpdate on the dimensions (which is more expensive)?

Comment: @GregGalloway Yes, when I am doing process database, it is ProcessFull.
and when I am choosing individual objects, then ProcessFull for all partitions and ProcessUpdate for all dimensions. Should I try for ProcessFull for all objects including dimensions?

Comment: @ScriptSoft what are you trying to accomplish? It would be an interesting test to prove ProcessFull on each object takes about the same time as ProcessFull on the database. But why not just ProcessFull the database? What’s your goal?

Comment: @GregGalloway, sorry for late reply, Here is scenario:
I have 33 measure group in 8 cube. each measure group has 3 partition based on year i.e  last 1 year, previous year then all rest of years. Currently when I was selecting just DB, it was processing full and is taking approx 6 hours. Now we have requirement to process just one year data, hence can not select full DB and need to select 1 year partition from each measure group along with dimensions.

Comment: @GregGalloway: To test above scenario, first I selected ALL dim and ALL partitions (which is equals to selecting whole DB) but it was taking approx 11 hours instead of 6 hours. As you had suggested, I made all Dim as ProcessFull, it worked and from 11 hours it came to 5:30 hours. Now same thing I am applying to process 1 year partitions with all dimensions with ProcessFull, but they are taking 5 hours. I was expecting it to reduce as 2:30 hours at least as per data. Request you to please help. let me know any clarification needed. Many Thanks.

Comment: This may be a bit much for a comment but I will walk you through what I do when I do an SSAS tuning project. I would test each dimension individually in SSMS doing a ProcessUpdate. That should tell you which is the culprit. Then I would dig into the structure of those slow processing dimensions. My guess is that the slow dimensions have millions of rows or dozens of attributes and no attribute relationships. My guess is that they are degenerate dimensions which are the same grain as a fact table. But please update your question with a screenshot of the Attribute Relationship tabs. We will see.

Comment: I would also process in SSMS each current year partition and identify which ones are the slow ones. ProcessData them. If any are slow then you may need to partition further. Then run ProcessIndexes and see if any are slow. If so maybe the aggs are heavy or you need to disable some indexes on large dimensions attributes you never filter directly on.

Comment: How many cores do you have on your server? Is SQL on the same server or separate?

Comment: How much free RAM does the SSAS server have at the peak memory usage of cube/dimension processing? Have you adjusted the LowMemoryLimit/TotalMemoryLimit server settings or are they the default which is 65 and 80 respectively? I assume your 12.0 mention above means you have SSAS 2014?

Comment: Yes, it is SSAS 2014. 
LowMemoryLimit/TotalMemoryLimit default values: 65 and 80 respectively.
server RAM: 128 GB
Available RAM while cube processing 70-80 GB approx
Server has 8 Virtual Processors.
there are approx 100 dimensions and 3 are Fact Dimensions in 2 cube out of 8.
Attribute relationship for ALL dimension's attributes is 'Flexible' by default.
Screenshot of one of culprit Fact dimensions is attached.
meanwhile I will try other troubleshooting options and revert back.
If you have any comment , please suggest. Many Thanks

Comment: @ScriptSoft the dimension you pictured above will run 16 `SELECT DISTINCT` SQL queries (one for each attribute then one huge query which asks for the ReportingEntityID and all 16 other Attribute keys in one wide query result. This takes time and memory. Can you split the dimension into several more tightly related dimensions? Can you add Attribute relationships?

Comment: Does the table behind Reporting Entity ever receive `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements? If is insert only then you can move to `ProcessAdd` which will save quite a bit of time.

Comment: @GregGalloway this dimension is a fact dimensions, hence receive transaction on daily basis with insert, update or delete. I know this one dim is bulky in terms of performance and I am also checking other option if it can be converted into normal dim or can be split. Based on how business bahave, I do also have plan to implement Attribute relationships.

Comment: related to this, i have couple of questions if you can please address: 1. if we apply 'Rigid' relationship and while processing, attribute identifies change, will cube be broken or will it comparatively be slow? 2. in SSIS, Analysis Services processing task editor, if we select 'Parallel process' option, all ssas objects(partitions, dim) will run in parallel?

Comment: 3.I am doing ProcessFull for all dim & one year partitions from each 33 MG,for which I am using ssis & SQL serever agent job. I am doing same for cube processing for all data for (all Dim and All partitions). Surprisingly process for one year (all dim+33 one year prtn) longer than the time taken by process for all data(all dim+3*33 partn). as per ur recommendation, I used 'ProcessFull instead of ProcessUpdate which reduced time significantly. But when same thing I am applying for '1 year process', its same and taking approx 5 hours. Do you see any reason here?

Comment: I wouldn’t recommend Rigid. It won’t impact the processing speed of the dimension itself; it will only reduce the number of aggs that need to be rebuilt in the ProcessIndexes phase of cube processing. The downside is if an Attribute relationship changes (like Texas was in USA and you decide to rename that to United States) the cube will not process at all and you will have to do a ProcessFull on the whole database.

Comment: Parallel process is recommended and may explain the difference between process full on the database vs. individual objects.

Comment: If you ProcessFull dimensions it will unprocess all measure groups (all partitions) so don’t follow that up with processing the current year partitions or last year will be unprocessed. That suggestion was just a test of performance.

Comment: And if you ProcessUpdate dimensions then process just the current year partitions, indexes and aggs on the prior year partitions will not be processed and query performance will suffer. So make sure you also do a ProcessIndexes on the cube to resolve that. It can happen all in the same transaction

Comment: In #3 do you mark it parallel? Can you include a screenshot? Regardless the prior year partition will be unprocessed so #3 won’t be feasible.

Comment: @GregGalloway, Thanks, but I am still not clear what may have been wrong in my 3rd point above - I am processing cube using SSIS in below 2 ways: 1. all 100 dim + All 99 partitions for all 3 years data using ProcessFull in one Analysis Services Processing Task. 2. ProcessFull for all 100 dim + 33 partitions for one year data in one Analysis Services Processing Task. 1st option taking 5 hours and 2nd option unexpectedly taking 6:15 hours, which should be either less or equals to 5 hours. Any clue where I can check?

Comment: Setting in both processing is exactly same. will share screenshot

Comment: @GregGalloway, Yes I mark it Parallel, attached is screenshot. Also do you mean that for option one (all 100 dim+33 partns-ProceessFull) remaining partitions will become 'Unprocess'? then what can be the more efficient way?

Comment: No. If you ProcessFull a Dimension then the data in the cube is wiped out. It is unprocessed. So #3 leaves prior years unqueryable.

Comment: I can’t explain why #3 is slower. Maybe the SQL source performance isn’t consistent? Maybe the prior test left the cube in a different state than before #2?

Comment: No problem Greg. Oracle source is fine. I am getting this result in every occurrences whenever I test. I will ProcessFull ssas db and then retry the same test to wipe out the possibility of being 'cube in different state' and will get back.

Comment: Also I learnt that if we have requirement to process only some of partitions(like 1 year data) then dimensions always should be ProcessUpdate, otherwise rest of the partitions will not be query-able. to let you know I am still trying in parallel to separate the dimension out.

Comment: Hello @GregGalloway, FYI, I tried further 2 ways: 1. Changed relationship of the dimensions from Fact to Regular under 'dimensionsUsage' tab. Idea was to change from fact dimension to normal dimensions.   2. Secondly I split the problem dimension into  2 normal dimension each having 9 attribute where 'Reporting Entity' as a key in each one of them. Unfortunately both trick didn't work. 1st one given same processing time and 2nd one even increased the time. Seems it can't be improved further.